# Drag and drop from outlook to webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, outlook

I'm looking for the following functionality and a push in the right direction if it is possible.

I would like to be able to drag an email that I have in Microsoft Outlook over to a webpage and have the webpage parse out details within that email.  Is this possible?

The intent is to take that data and interface with our help desk software API to automatically log work orders from emails that are recieved almost daily from an outside system.

Comment: You can try with Java applets. It is possible to do it with it. Here's the first Google result: http://panyasan.wordpress.com/2008/02/29/open-source-drag-drop-upload-java-applet-for-websites/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachment-from-email-client/17197224#17197224

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not be possible. But you could save the email as *.eml and then upload it to a website. An other cool solution would be to forward the email to a service which parses the email.

---

PS: In Firefox 3.6 local file drag and drop will be supported, see: http://www.bruechner.de/md5file/js/