# Implementing a Drag-and-Drop function from MS Outlook into our web application

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, outlook

We’re looking for some development guidelines/assistance with respect to implementing a Drag-and-Drop function from MS Outlook into our web application (currently in development). Our ultimate aim is for our users to be able to drag emails from their Outlook instance into our application running in their browser. As it stands we’re able to achieve this functionality with a file (for example from the user’s desktop) but not directly from Outlook.

Our application is being developed using Visual Studio for PHP and an SQL Server 2012 backend.

Our progress so far:
•   We have an HTML5 control on our page which receives the javascript onDrop/OnDropStart/etc events and is able to enumerate and retrieve the content therein, files or otherwise;
•   When dragging emails (or other objects such as contacts) from Outlook (tested in Outlook 2010), we’re able to enumerate plain text data but not the MIME content of the email (message or attachments)
•   We’re able to enumerate and retrieve plain text and HTML content of an email by Ctrl+A on the contents and dragging that into the HTML control.

Where we need assistance is in understanding how to access and retrieve the full MIME content of an email from the drag/drop events the browser has access to. We’re aware of the PIO package for Visual Studio which would enable this for a local .NET application however we don’t appear to be able to use that for a web application.

As the product is in early development phase we’re open to suggestions and directions from Microsoft as to how we might best achieve this, including if we can get this done using .NET or ASP controls for the web application.

Comment: This is a very broad question and admits many answers and discussions. Please, make specific questions. Check p.e. http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for SO guidelines for questions

Answer (score 4):

See [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224)

In theory, you can create a browser helper object (dll) for IE (*it is possible to do that for other browsers, see Google Gears*) that installs its own drag/drop handler on the browser window and saves the old `IDropTarget` object. When a message is dragged from Outlook, you will get `CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR` and `CF_FILECONTENTS` formats (*which IE does not understand*), create a temporary file, and pass fake `CF_HDROP` (*which IE knows how to handle*) to the old drop handler provided by the browser.

I did this twice (*FF 3.6 and IE*), and it seems to work just fine.

Also keep in mind that Outlook does not keep in the original MIME source. When dragging, the best you can do is get the message in the MSG format, which you can then read using either Extended MAPI (*C++ or Delphi*) or straight COM API (*MSG is an OLE storage file*).

Comment: Hi, I'd love to see any sample code you have for this - I want to implement exactly this but have very little C++ experience and no experience writing DLLs. I also couldn't find anything to do with custom drag and drop handlers in a BHO in the Google Gears source, so if you have a link to the actual source code that does this, I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

OMG I FOUND A FREE SOLUTION:
https://tonyfederer.github.io/OutlookFileDrag/

I looked at https://outlook2web.com/

and https://www.wilutions.info/ddaddin-download.html

but the free one works fine, and it's open source! Woo hoo! I really needed it.