# Drag & Drop directly from Outlook in web app

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, outlook

I know this question is relating the same problem as mine :

- [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224)

but I'm looking for a workaround to achieve a drop from Outlook message into my webapp (currently only HTML5 / JS code).

Is it possible, with some activeX, to copy the message in a temp filesystem folder and then use this file reference ? I would like to know the faisability level.

Also, is it right that we can call a DLL from Jscript using ActiveX, like :

```
var obj = new ActiveXObject("ABCDll.testMethod");
var vResult = obj.TestMethod();
alert(vResult);
```

BTW, if someone has any other suggestion to do a working Drag&Drop component (IE complient) for ANY files, incl. emails from Outlook (the only things that is not working for now...)

Thanks a lot for any input.

Comment: Did the answer by Dmitry work?

Comment: Yes, I did write a custom browser helper who write the uploaded file(s) into a temp directory, and then call a javascript handle.

Comment: Have a look at this answer! Works perfect for web browsers and Outlook 2013/2016 https://stackoverflow.com/a/49679156/3825124

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a browser helper (for IE) in C++ or Delphi that retrieves the current drag/drop handler from IE and installs its own handler. When a message is dragged from Outlook, you can save it to a temp folder, then invoke the original drag/drop handler. After the handler returns, the temporary file can be deleted.

I have done this in the past, and it works fine. You might want to looks at the Google Gears source code (no longer supported) that intercepts drag/drop in IE.

Comment: I've write a BHO who's getting my "drop-destination" DIV and i'm now trying to attach a DropEvent to this DIV. However, i'm only able to use put_onDragStart(), I didn't find an event with DROP event... I've search for some tutorial or example where drag/drop handler are implement but without success. Can I ask you some input ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Google Gears source code? You will need to drop all the way down to the Windows API level.

Comment: @Dmitry, I don't suppose you've got some sample code you could show  us for the BHO you refer to?

Comment: No, it is a part of a commercial product, sorry.

Answer (score 10):

Outlook uses the [CFSTR_FILECONTENTS and CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx) formats that many applications do not understand. [My solution](http://www.wilutions.com/ddaddin/index.html) for this problem uses an [Outlook Add-in](https://www.wilutions.info/ddaddin.html) to intercept the D&D and convert the proprietary format into a usual file drop (CF_HDROP).

The Add-in replaces the DoDragDrop function pointer in the import table of OLE32.DLL with a wrapper function (inside Outlook's memory address space). The wrapper converts the D&D data and calls the original function.

[This article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5178/DLL-Injection-and-function-interception-tutorial) describes how to hook into an import table. Outlook's D&D stream format is explained [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28209/Outlook-Drag-and-Drop-in-C). The stream data has to be written into (temp) files in order to provide a simple [CF_HDROP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902(v=vs.85).aspx#CF_HDROP).

Comment: Is that functionality can only be done using C++? Do you know if something similar can be achieved using C#?