# HTML 5 drag and Drop email from outlook

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop, outlook, oledragdrop

I am working on a Ember.JS based application with HTML 5 drag and drop file upload. I have came across a requirement where user wants to upload outlook emails using Drag and Drop. It seems that JavaScript can not recognize outlook messages as files.

Is there any way to get a reference to outlook message and upload it as a file in JavaScript Or Bridge OLE drag and drop with JS

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924528/drag-drop-directly-from-outlook-in-web-app and

Comment: Hi! Did you find a solution for this problem? I'm trying to create an HTML5 app that can receive dropped outlook emails. For some reason, when I drag an email straight from outlook to my html div, it's going through my drop function but my datatransfer.files is empty.

Comment: Hi Nicole, there is no straight forward solution to this. We had to create java applet to capture the drop event for outlook. Please let me know if you need more information on this. 

Below links can also be helpful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client?lq=1 and 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19924528/drag-drop-directly-from-outlook-in-web-app?lq=1

Answer (score 2):

There are paid solutions:

1. **Outlook2Web**: https://outlook2web.com/
2. **DragDrop**: https://www.dragdrop.com/

And, I found a free solution on GitHub.

**Outlook File Drag**: https://github.com/tonyfederer/OutlookFileDrag

Answer (score -5):

Have you considered `Exporting` emails to a file then `Importing` it to Jquery ?
From outlook:

```
File > Open & Export > Export to a file > Comma separated values > Inbox
```

Outlook sample file :

```
"Subject","Body","From: (Name)","From: (Address)","From: (Type)","To: (Name)","To: (Address)","To: (Type)","CC: (Name)","CC: (Address)","CC: (Type)","BCC: (Name)","BCC: (Address)","BCC: (Type)","Billing Information","Categories","Importance","Mileage","Sensitivity"
"dsds","Dmisa csadfdsafs
Hey Hello World

Kind Regards
Test Message

",,,,"test@gmail.com","test@gmail.com","SMTP",,,,,,,,,"Normal",,"Normal"
```

The user can also save as a specific message

Comment: The user specifically said drag and drop!