# JavaFX - Outlook attachments - DnD

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, outlook, javafx-8

Hello i need a DnD Solution to Drag Outlook Mail Attachments to a Stackpane.

JavaFX / Outlook 2010

```
    stackpaneDragAndDropZone.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) -> {
        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
        System.out.println(db.getContentTypes());
    });
```

Has this Output:

```
[[message/external-body;access-type=clipboard;index=0;name="faxdoc-150217-1300-+49-206581978.pdf"], [RenPrivateItem]]
```

How can i use this RenPrivateItem?

On regular Java i got a file with this code:

```
    dropTarget.addDropTargetListener(new DropTargetAdapter() {
        public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
            Transferable t = dtde.getTransferable();

            try {
                DataFlavor[] dataFlavors = t.getTransferDataFlavors();

                dtde.acceptDrop(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);

                //create a temp file
                File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp");

                for (int i = 0; i < dataFlavors.length; i++) {
                    File file = new File(t.getTransferData(dataFlavors[i]).toString().replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
                    Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File(file.getCanonicalPath()));
                }

                dtde.dropComplete(true);

            } catch (Exception ex) {

                ex.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a private format as the name suggests. But you will get CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CF_FILECONTENTS formats.

Comment: thanks, nevertheless i search for a solution to get the path of the attachment in my javafx application.

Comment: "path of the attachment"? Are you not the one who adds the attachment to begin with?

Comment: i have a mail with the attachment and drag and drop the attachment from outlook to my javafx application. how i get the attachment file? this is my problem. i get only this: 
[[message/external-body;access-type=clipboard;index=0;name="faxdoc-1502 17-1300-+49-206581978.pdf"], [RenPrivateItem]] 
and have no idea how i can use this on javafx!?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224

Comment: I don't know, sorry - I do not use Java.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This only works for the system clipboard. Still unable to get the dragboard to work with outlook attachments.

You can take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166666/4489577

Essentially if you know you have something with message/external-body;access-type=clipboard, you can use:

```java
DataFormat df = DataFormat.lookupMimeType("message/external-body");
if (df == null) {
  df = new DataFormat("message/external-body");
}
Object inMemoryFile = clipboard.getContent(df);
```

to access it. Using the full mime type gives null when you use getContent().

Then you can just cast it to ByteBuffer and do whatever you want with the file's bytes.

Comment: `pane.setOnDragOver((DragEvent event) ->
        {
            event.getDragboard().getContent(DataFormat.lookupMimeType("message/external-body"));
            System.exit(0);
        });` never quits the app... or in other words, it never gets to the second line...

Comment: Can you show a full working example? It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Sorry, I only tested the system clipboard. I'm still trying to get to the bottom of why the dragboard doesn't work.

Comment: I tried with the system clipboard and it’s also the same issue …