# Drag n drop Outlook email into aspx page

Tags: asp.net, drag-and-drop, outlook

I am currently developing a Asp.net web site where i need functionality of file uploading by drag-drop. 
I developed file uploading by drag-drop but i am facing issue with MS Outlook. 
user need to first save outlook mail to some folder and from there he/she need to drag-drop in website.
We need functionality that user can directly drag-drop outlook email to the website because a single user will be uploading hundreds of email daily.

Can any one provide some idea how i can achieve it? we can use any Javascript, AxtiveX, Applet or Flash etc.
Any solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There is not much you can do. See [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224). You can try to replace the default browser's drag/drop handler, but you'd need to get your code into browser process.