# Dropzone.js - drop outlook emails

Tags: javascript, file, upload, outlook, dropzone.js

We have Dropzone successfully set up in our browser application and it works great! However, we are trying find a way to drag and drop emails from MS Outlook and we have not had any success. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that unless you override the IDropTarget interface of the browser.
See [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224)

Comment: I have an Outlook `.msg` file on windows desktop, and even setting `aceptedFiles: "application/vnd.ms-outlook"` it won't accept this file. is there any workaround ?