# is it possible to drag and drop emails from outlook to a web php form

Tags: php, outlook

We are trying to implement a feature which I have not been able to find before on SO.

The problem: we have our current system on access and we are trying to move it to a web based system. Access provides a really easy way of dragging and dropping emails inside its body.

However is it possible to do the same with PHP? Any heads up will he appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No web browsers can handle CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CF_FILECONTENTS formats. See [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224)