# Drag & drop attachment from Outlook to Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drag-and-drop, outlook

Is there a possibility to use HTML5 files API to drag & drop attachment directly from outlook to Chrome browser? I can use files API in javascript in browser to detect regular files drag&drop, as well as images drag & drop from other websites to mine, but drag&drop from outlook doesn't work, I cannot even see the dataTransfer.

```
function dragdrop_done(ev)
{
   var oe=ev.originalEvent;
   var dt=oe.dataTransfer;
   console.log(dt.types); // logs ["Files"] for dragging files
                          // or ["text/html"] for dragging images from other sites
                          // but empty [] when dropping attachments from outlook
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachement-from-email-client/17197224#17197224