# Drag&Drop to Outlook add-in

Tags: outlook-addin

I have a problem with Outlook 365 add-in we are developing. The add-in should accept files dragged from user desktop. The web page is working fine with Drag&Drop in any browser: IE, Edge, Opera.

Same web page in add-in accepts only files dragged from Office 365 Application and doesn't accept anything from Outlook, user desktop, any other website or app.

So in fact add-in is droppable and working fine, but only for files dragged from Office 365 App.

Is there any special security setting in place?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachment-from-email-client/17197224#17197224

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachment-from-email-client)

Answer (score 0):

The web browser which hosts your web add-in doesn't recognize and understand the format which is used for dragged items from Outlook. On the page [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachment-from-email-client/17197224#17197224) you may find the following explanation:

> All browsers are only expecting the actual file drag/drop format (CF_HDROP), but when dragging from Outlook, there is no file on the filesystem. What you get is the CF_FILEDESCRIPTOR and CF_FILECONTENTS formats. No browser that I know of (not even IE), knows how to handle that.

Comment: The problem is that the browser (Edge) which hosts the add-in doesn't accept DROPS from anything (even file explorer) except links dragged from Office365 application.