# Copy mail from Outlook and paste msg-file to file input

Tags: javascript, outlook, clipboard, msg, clipboarddata

Copying different files into the *input* such as xlxs, png, msg, etc. works perfectly.
What I wish to accomplish is being able to copy mails directly from Outlook into the *input* (as msg-files).

#### The problem:

If I copy a mail from Outlook with the current solution I get vague information such as the subject, sent date, receiver etc - Just as if you would paste the clipboard into notepad.

#### The Goal:

If you copy a mail from Outlook into a word document for example, it creates a clickable msg-file. This is the file I'd like to paste into my *input*.

Right now, I've to copy the mail from Outlook, paste it into word, copy it again, to finally being able to paste the msg-file into the *input*

> 

**HTML:**

```
<div id="documentUploadDiv">
  <div id="filedataholder" filebase64data="" hasfile="false"></div>
  <div id="filereaderdialog_filegroup">
    <input type="file" id="filedatareader_filegroup">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Script:**

```
window.addEventListener('paste', e => {
try{          
    $('#filedatareader_filegroup').get(0).files = e.clipboardData.files;
    $('#filedatareader_filegroup').trigger("change");

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.clipboardData.files[0]);

    $("#filedataholder").attr("filebase64data", reader.result) 
  
    }catch(e){
        console.error(e)
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you develop a web application? Where do you need to grab the data?

Comment: Yeah it's a web application. In the outlook inbox you can right click on a mail to copy it.
Pasting that clipboard into a word document or to a directory/filepath, will create a msg-file. Pasting the clipboard into an html input (type=file) will not :(

Answer (score 0):

That is because Outlook copies its message in multiple clipboard formats, but FileContents/Filename are not available since there is no real file on the file system.

See [Upload fails when user drags and drops attachment from email client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17184369/upload-fails-when-user-drags-and-drops-attachment-from-email-client/17197224#17197224) for a similar issue.

[image]

Comment: Okey, thanks alot!
Looks like I'll have to accept defeat for this one : /